# Join in Esqueleto between different types

Tags: haskell, esqueleto

I'm trying to use Esqueleto on an existing database and I encountered this problem : two columns that I need to join are of a different types. One is Integer (normal), the other (the "foreign key") is a String instead of being an Integer :-(

Writting the join in standard SQL works fine, but with Esqueleto, it complains that types mismtach (which is true but I don't care). Is there a workaround (like doing a 'convert' in Esqueleto or being able to add raw ON criteria) ??

Comment: In what flavour of SQL is it OK to join integers to strings and what does that mean?  It's not OK in Postgres.

Comment: @tom: MySQL. Apparently it convert the string into Int. `SELECT 1 == "1 hello" => 1.